# Foreign Key From Table in Another Services

Tags: api, laravel-9, laravel-migrations

How can I create a foreign key that takes a primary key from a table in another service using an API and put it into my local table as a foreign key in Laravel? Is that possible?
Please help me, as I don't know how to do this correctly.